# Directory.CreateDirectory() returns "Accss to the path '..\\[folder]\\' is denied." exception when used with SpecFlow test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, specflow

I'm working on creating some unit tests using SpecFlow & NUnit.

A requirement for one of my tests is to create a number of test folders. However, the test run is returning "Accss to the path '..\TestFolder1\' is denied." exception. I've checked and double checked that I have write permissions in the parent folder, have tried sharing the parent folder and have ensured that the parent folder or any of its contents are not marked read-only but the error persists.

```
public static string[] CreateTestFolders()
    {
        _testFolders = new string[] { @"..\TestFolder1\", @"..\TestFolder2\", @"..\TestFolder3\", @"..\TestFolder4\", @"..\TestFolder5\" };

        for (int i = 0; i < _testFolders.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_testFolders[i]);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string exm = Environment.UserName + " " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        return _testFolders;
    }
```

This application already had unit tests applied using MSTest; this method is called in the [ClassInitialize] test setup and executes without issue, however attempts to call the method from the SpecFlow step method still return the same exception.

I'm struggling to understand the problem here. Is there something specific to SpecFlow testing or NUnit that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the issue was with NUnit.
Tests executed with MSTest return the bin folder of the test project as Environment.CurrentDirectory, "C:\Code[test_project_folder]\bin\Debug"; tests executed with NUnit return "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW". 
The access denied issue arose as a result of the CurrentDirectory being a subdirector of the "Program Files (x86)" folder.

In order to work around this issue, I added a testDirectory string parameter to my helper method...

```
public static string[] CreateTestFolders(string testDirectory)
{
    _testFolders = new string[] { @"TestFolder1", @"TestFolder2", @"TestFolder3", @"TestFolder4", @"TestFolder5" };

    for (int i = 0; i < _testFolders.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            _testFolders[i] = Directory.CreateDirectory(testDirectory + _testFolders[i]).FullName;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exm = Environment.UserName + " " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return _testFolders;
}
```

... and updated my method call to pass AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory as argument...

```
_testFileFolders = StepHelper.CreateTestFolders(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

This fix yielded the result I was chasing.

Comment: Glad it's fixed!

Comment: Although you've solved it for your own purposes, you may want to know that NUnit provides `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
public static string[] CreateTestFolders()
{
    _testFolders = new string[] { @"TestFolder1", @"TestFolder2", @"TestFolder3", @"TestFolder4", @"TestFolder5" };

    for (int i = 0; i < _testFolders.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            // Also try with Application.StartupPath instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
            string currentPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), _testFolders[i]);
            if (!Directory.Exists(currentPath)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath);
            }
            //at this point your folder should exist
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exm = Environment.UserName + " " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return _testFolders;
}
```

Try using DirectorySecurity as mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I had the same issue when creating a directory. I used DirectorySecurity as shown below:

```
// Define Security Rules
var securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
securityRules.AddAccessRule(new 
FileSystemAccessRule(@"Domain\AdminAccount1", FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
// ...

// ...
// Use the security rules while creating directory
var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(_testFolders[i], securityRules);
```

Comment: I attempted the addition of DirectorySecurity; issue is unaffected; access denied exception still returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just doesn't like the double dot notation, use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead, or just do the following:

```
DirectoryInfo cd = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
cd.CreateDirecory("TestFolder1"); // creates a relative Directory
```

Comment: I tried this: removed ..\ from folder name; the directory returned by Environment.CurrentDirectory was not what I expected (i.e. the bin folder in the SpecFlow test project) but instead 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW'. Access denied issue persists.

Comment: Executing the original unit test (MSTest), Environment.CurrentDirectory returns "C:\Code\[test_project_folder]\bin\Debug".
Executing the SpecFlow/NUnit test, Environment.CurrentDirectory returns "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW".

What's going on here? Does SpecFlow/NUnit execute tests in a different folder from the test project bin folder? Why?

Comment: Posted fix above; Environment.CurrentDirectory as outlined in previous comment was the issue. Thanks for looking.